# Select a specific window X11

Tags: c, x11

I am designing an app that having the ID of an X11 window to draw a rectangle.
The problem I have is that I can not draw nothing in the window.

[Code](http://pastebin.com/1nTb2cMw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious error is that you did not select `ExposureMask` in call to `XSelectInput`, so you will not receive `Expose` event you are waiting for.

Other possible problem is not setting foreground drawing color of the `GC` by `XSetForegroundColor`, default is black. And using default gc of screen may fail if the window has different color depth or different visual. Other important GC attributes is`subwindow_mode` (whether to draw over child windows).

Still, after I did those changes, the program only works for me (draws a rectangle) on root window and xev, but not for xterm, no expose events.

This is my fixed version:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

        Window win;
        Display *display;
        XEvent e;
        display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
if(display==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open Display\n");
exit(1);
}
        int s = DefaultScreen(display);
        //unsigned long *id = (unsigned long*)(argv[1]);
        sscanf(argv[1], "0x%x", &win);
        if(!XSelectInput(display,win,StructureNotifyMask | ExposureMask)){
                fprintf(stderr,"Cannot select Display\n");
        return -1;
        }
        if(!XMapWindow(display,win)){
                fprintf(stderr,"Cannot map Display\n");
        return -1;
        }

        XGCValues gcv;
        gcv.subwindow_mode = IncludeInferiors;
        GC gc = XCreateGC(display, win, GCSubwindowMode,
          &gcv);
        XSetForeground(display, gc, 0xff00ff00);
        XSetPlaneMask(display, gc, 0xffffffff);

        while (1) {
          puts("waiting for event\n");
          XNextEvent(display, &e);
          puts("got event\n");
          if (e.type == Expose) {
            printf("drawing\n");
            XFillRectangle(display, win, gc, 20, 20, 100, 100);
          }
          if (e.type == KeyPress)
             break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```